# Get duplicate files from a directory in shell

Tags: shell

How would I get duplicate files from a directory? I want to ignore the version number of the file.

```
directory
   httpcore-4.3.jar
   httpcore.jar
   http.jar
```

I want `httpcore` in return.
The easiest way I can think of is

```
allfiles <-- readAllFileNames()
for file1 in allfiles
    for file2 in allfiles
       compare file1 and file2 by ignoring version
```

Is there any another efficient way?

Comment: You’re defining “duplicate” as “multiple files which, if you removed the version number from the name, would have the same name”? How are you defining version number? There are a lot of version numbering schemes and something that works for `4.3` won’t necessarily catch `4.3.1` or `4.3rc1` or something.

Comment: if you removed the version number from the name, would have the same name”? -> yes . I am dealing with pretty std version numbers that you mentioned.

Comment: Generate checksums for each file once - find duplicate checksums.

Comment: Generating checksum means comparing contents of a file. I just want to check with their name.

Comment: Thanks for down voting.

Comment: I think the downvotes are because it is difficult-to-impossible to answer this question without an understanding of what qualifies as a version number, like I said. If I read your comment right, `4.3rc1` is still a potential version number; if I had tried to do this I wouldn’t have caught it. Would it be everything after a hyphen, or everything after the first digit?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with `sed` and `uniq` if you can define a regular expression to match a version number:

```
ls | sed -r 's/(v?-[[:digit:]].*)?\.[[:alpha:]]+$//' | uniq --repeated
```

This particular regular expression matches anything a hyphen followed by a digit (assuming that’s the start of a version number), and in any case matches the file extension, and removes them.

```
$ ls -Fl
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dhouck dhouck 0 Aug  2 10:28 httpcore-4.3.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dhouck dhouck 0 Aug  2 10:28 httpcore.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dhouck dhouck 0 Aug  2 10:28 http.jar
$ ls | sed -r 's/(v?-[[:digit:]].*)?\.[[:alpha:]]+$//' | uniq --repeated
httpcore
```

Here’s what the `sed` command does, in detail, in case you want to change it:

- `-r`: Use extended regular expressions, which make it easier to use
  some of the fancy stuff below.
- `s/`…`/`…`/`: Begin a “substitute” command. Take everything between the first and second slashes as a regular expression, and replace it with what’s between the second and third slashes. In this case, what’s between the second and third slashes is nothing, so this just gets rid of whatever was matched.
- `(`…`)?`: The parentheses make a group, so that everything between them is treated as a single unit. The question mark indicates that this group is optional. This is for the version number, which might not exist.

  - `-`: Matches a literal `-` character, since a version number is usually set off from everything else with a hyphen.
  - `v?`: Optionally matches the character `v`, since that is sometimes used before the version number. You might want to remove this if you have something named `javascript-v8-6.0.jar` or something.
  - `[[:digit:]]`: Matches a single digit.
  - `.*`: The `.` matches any character, and the `*`

  Together, these indicate that a version number is anything after the first hyphen followed by a digit. This works in the case of `package-3.2-beta-1.jar`, but not will match too much in the case of `graphics-3d-7.1`.
- The next part, which isn’t grouped in the regular expression, is for the file extension. It seems you want to remove this too; if you don’t, wrap the below in parentheses, and instead of an empty substitution (the part between the second and third slashes), use `\2`, which means “the contents of capturing group 2”. The version would be the first capturing group, and the entire matched expression including both the version and extension would be group 0.

  - `\.`: Matches a literal `.`. The backslash is needed because `.` by itself matches anything, as mentioned above.
  - `[[:alpha:]]`: Matches any letter
  - `+`: Do the previous part (`[[:alpha:]]`) one or more times. This allows extensions of `.o`, `.sh`, `.jar`, `.java`, `.class`, etc.
- `$`: Anchor at the end of the line (the file name). This ensures that you won’t match a fake “extension” in the middle of a file name if there’s a stray period somewhere.

The `uniq --repeated` will take all of these lines and tell you which ones are duplicates. It requires sorted input, but `ls`’s output is already sorted and the `sed` script shouldn’t change that.